# Why is install4j adding empty lines in my xml file

Tags: xpath, install4j

I'm using the "Replace text in XML files" action in my install4j project a lot of times. My problem is, that it adds one empty line in the xml file every time I use this action.

This is my example XPath expression.

```xml
/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='KpsInstallPath']/@value
```

Any idea what I can do against this behaviour? The xml file is important after the installation, and it#s hard to read with that many empty lines (at the moment 10 per XPath expression for 20 entries)

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of the nodes this expression refers to?

Answer (score 0):

The node ends with a linebreak that is not part of the semantic XML model. It's just part of the textual representation. This leads to this symptom. There is no way around this except to trim these linebreaks yourself, either with custom code or with the action "Modify text files with regular expression".
It would be nice (imo) to have an action like "Pretty-print XML" aftwerwards.

A custom code example follows:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;

public static void prettyPrintXML(String filePath) throws Exception {
    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    File out = new File(filePath);
    try (final FileReader reader = new FileReader(out)) {
        org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlUtil.prettyFormat(new FileReader(new File(filePath)), writer);    
    }
    Files.write(out.toPath(), writer.getBuffer().toString().replace(System.lineSeparator()+System.lineSeparator(), "").getBytes());

}
```

That can be added here:
[image]

With the code using this JAR here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-utils/3.3.0.

This cleaned up my XML nicely.